# App throws exception that web.config was modified but it's not

Tags: c#, azure, webforms, azure-web-app-service

I'm facing strange problem on azure app service with my asp.net web forms site.

Got exception:

```
ConfigurationErrorsExceptionSystem.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord in EvaluateOne

The configuration file has been changed by another program. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\web.config)

ConfigurationErrorsException: The configuration file has been changed by another program. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\web.config)
  Module "System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord", line 72, col 0, in EvaluateOne
System.Object EvaluateOne(System.String[], System.Configuration.SectionInput, Boolean, System.Configuration.FactoryRecord, System.Configuration.SectionRecord, System.Object)
  Module "System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord", line 515, col 0, in Evaluate
Boolean Evaluate(System.Configuration.FactoryRecord, System.Configuration.SectionRecord, System.Object, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
  Module "System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord", line 666, col 0, in GetSectionRecursive
Void GetSectionRecursive(System.String, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, Boolean, System.Object ByRef, System.Object ByRef)
  Module "System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord", line 0, col 0, in GetSection
System.Object GetSection(System.String)
  Module "System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig", line 0, col 0, in GetSectionObject
System.Object GetSectionObject(System.String)
  Module "System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig", line 19, col 0, in GetSection
System.Object GetSection(System.String, System.Type, ResultsIndex)
  Module "System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig", line 0, col 0, in get_Authorization
System.Web.Configuration.AuthorizationSection get_Authorization()
  Module "System.Web.Security.UrlAuthorizationModule", line 153, col 0, in OnEnter
Void OnEnter(System.Object, System.EventArgs)
  Module "System.Web.HttpApplication+SyncEventExecutionStep", line 65, col 0, in System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute
Void System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
  Module "System.Web.HttpApplication", line 21, col 0, in ExecuteStep
System.Exception ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep, Boolean ByRef)
```

YSOD with Exception is throw after 10-15minutes application deploy.App is not restarting it's just showing YSOD.

But no one edited web.config. Date modified didn't change and nor did the content - compared with win merge and files are identical (one straight after deploy with one that throws exception).

After manually saving web.config (without any changes) file or re deploying app problem is resolved for next 10-15 minutes.

**@Edit1**

Tried also:

- deploy it as another app service - not working
- run it locally not on
  azure (working so it seems to be connected with azure app service
  host).

**@Edit2**

We got first error in logs from 6.6.2017 and it occured from time to time (i'd say once a week. But it's test environment with very low traffic) till two days ago (27.06.2017). Then It just exploded and happens all the time.

**@Edit3**

I Downloaded source files from symbol server and debugged it.

Current version returned from method GetStreamVersion is strange. Last write time is 10 minutes before creation time. (maybe it's somehow connected with 10-15 before app crashes?)

Where Last version which is compared with current version is normal. Created before last write.

No idea why creation time is modified. I double checked it on kudu with powershell and everything seems to be ok (values are the same as in lastVersion).

currentVersion:

- CreatedTime: {6/29/2017 10:28:30 AM}
- LastWriteTime: {6/29/2017 10:17:18 AM}

lastVersion:

- CreatedTime: {6/28/2017 8:50:11 AM}
- LastWriteTime: {6/29/2017 10:17:18 AM}

Times taken with kudu for web.config:

- CreationTime   : 6/28/2017 8:50:11 AM
- LastWriteTime  : 6/29/2017 10:17:18 AM
- LastAccessTime : 6/28/2017 8:50:11 AM

https://github.com/Microsoft/referencesource/blob/master/System.Configuration/System/Configuration/BaseConfigurationRecord.cs#L3988

Comment: Can you try to host it in another device and check if is a server device problem? It would be great to know if you are editing de app config by code, and if that, share the code

Comment: We have the exact same issue. This started yesterday and we still have no solution. 100% sure we don't do any web.config change. The error is keep coming back even after restart. This looks like a global Azure issue?

Comment: @Ferus7 Tried also:
- deploy it as another app service - not working
- run it locally not on azure (working so it seems to be connected with azure app service host).

Comment: @JeroenSlor Do you have the same problem that it occurs after 10-15minutes? In our case Both overriding web.config and restart helps but only for 10-15minutes.

Comment: @Pawel yes the error is coming back after a while :(

Comment: @JeroenSlor is it also webforms hosted as azure app service?

Comment: @Pawel no .net mvc hosted using azure webapps, we have other clients also running on azure with the same issue.

Comment: so looks like an external/azure issue?

Comment: Yes, please retweet: https://twitter.com/jeroenslor/status/880371993782226944

Comment: We created a support to azure, they are working on it, no response yet.

Comment: @Pawel the timings are exactly the same!

Comment: Please try setting SCM_TOUCH_WEBCONFIG_AFTER_DEPLOYMENT to 0 in appsettings of Azure portal and check whether it helps.

Comment: @Amor-MSFT Right now i am unable to reproduce this error so I can't check if it helped :/ It seems strange that it suddenly stopped occuring. Did you fix anything on your site?

Comment: @JeroenSlor are you still facing problems? I'm unable to reproduce this error right now...

Comment: Now, this is funky. I get this error when I try to access our app from Switzerland, while it works fine when I'm accessing it from Serbia. We are using CloudFlare in front of Azure. I wonder if it has something to do with the way CloudFlare forwards the requests, or with some Azure internal geolocation based request forwarding. Does anyone else have the same setup?

Comment: Since there seems to be some doubt about whether Azure have fixed this problem, I can confirm that, of yesterday, the problem is still occurring. I have made the two settings given as a workaround, and can confirm that they do seem to work in that I have no re-occurrences in the last 24 hours, and they were quite regular. So, the workaround fixed the problem for me, but the Azure problem remains.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Received response from the Azure team:

> Setting WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE_FCN_MODE = 1 try it first, as per issue behavior it should address the issue. If this setting does not heal we need to go for WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE = 0

Side note:

> Setting WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE_FCN_MODE = 1 should not lead to
>   performance impact. Setting  WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE = 0 may slightly
>   impact the performance during initial loads if website content size is
>   huge.

They are still investigating why this problem occurred all the sudden.

Comment: We set those flags and we are no longer facing those issues. Anyway there is no guarantee that those flags helped because before we applied this error was occuring very rarely. So it seems that azure fixed something on their side also.

Answer (score 2):

The error has come and go for me over the last few days, and I haven't managed to work out what settings or behaviour is causing it. So far;

- Restarting the Web app worked for me on a site with no additional deployment slots configured.
- On a different site, with multiple deployment slots, only a re-deployment seems to work.

I haven't tried either of Jeroen's solutions yet, as I feel more comfortable doing a restart or re-deployment than changing a setting I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

Please make sure you are using

```
WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE = 0
```

Do not use WEBSITE**S**_DYNAMIC_CACHE = 0 as it won't work.

Answer (score 1):

It looked like @JeroenSlor answer also helped me for some period of time, but after next App deployment it came back again. So mentioned flags looks like had some placebo effect.

If you look at Environment variables set on your WebApp (https://[yourwebapp].scm.azurewebsites.net/Env.cshtml), you will see a list of variables as:

```
WEBSITE_AUTH_ENABLED = False
WEBSITE_COMPUTE_MODE = Dedicated
WEBSITE_CURRENT_STAMPNAME = <...>
WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE = 1
WEBSITE_HOME_STAMPNAME = <...>
WEBSITE_HOSTNAME = <...>.azurewebsites.net
WEBSITE_HTTPLOGGING_ENABLED = 0
...and much more
```

If you will look at this list, you will find there is mentioned `WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE = 1`.

But.. please spot the difference - it's `WEBSITE_`, not `WEBSITES_` as suggested previously.
So I guess flags should be `WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE_FCN_MODE` and `WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE`, but it's only my guess, since it's really hard to find any official response about it.

I'm not blaming, just really trying to find the real fix.;)

Comment: well you are right. it's WEBSITE_DYNAMIC_CACHE. It's exactly what i set up.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft Support (we raised a ticket on this in parallel with finding this post) - there is a small error in this - it should be WEBSITE - not WEBSITES.

Answer (score 1):

If anyone is still struggling with the issue, for our case removing the

```
<location>
```

tag from the web.config helped.

Not sure why, but I suspect that having a location tag in the web.config somehow causes problem with the GetStreamVersion method mentioned by the op.