# Azure websites - The configuration file has been changed by another program

Tags: asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service

Last 2 days I've been plagued on my azure websites app with following exception:

Exception information:
Exception type: **ConfigurationErrorsException**

Exception message: **The configuration file has been changed by another program**. (D:\home\site\wwwroot\web.config)

It comes periodically each 5 minutes [or so], after app restart it goes ok for a while then it does again.

**Is there a way how to debug what's causing the config file change?** I have went through the whole code and have not found any reference for config file edition

Stack trace:

```
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.EvaluateOne(String[] keys, SectionInput input, Boolean isTrusted, FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.Evaluate(FactoryRecord factoryRecord, SectionRecord sectionRecord, Object parentResult, Boolean getLkg, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSectionRecursive(String configKey, Boolean getLkg, Boolean checkPermission, Boolean getRuntimeObject, Boolean requestIsHere, Object& result, Object& resultRuntimeObject)
at System.Configuration.BaseConfigurationRecord.GetSection(String configKey)
at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSectionObject(String sectionName)
at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.GetSection(String sectionName, Type type, ResultsIndex index)
at System.Web.Configuration.RuntimeConfig.get_HttpRuntime()
at System.Web.HttpContext.EnsureTimeout()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.OnThreadEnterPrivate(Boolean setImpersonationContext)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ResumeSteps(Exception error)
at System.Web.HttpApplication.BeginProcessRequestNotification(HttpContext context, AsyncCallback cb)
at System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context)
```

Comment: Have you checked the config file, before and after the exception? Is the config file before and after the same? If not, what have been changed?

Comment: I did now...it's hard to determine, because in azure portal I've also added application insights to help me track down the issue. Anyway, different lines are:


<httpModules>
      <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" />
    </httpModules>

 <add name="ApplicationInsightsWebTracking" type="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Web.ApplicationInsightsHttpModule, Microsoft.AI.Web" preCondition="managedHandler" />

<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />

Comment: I'm nostly curious about the <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />  line, not sure if it was added by the Microsoft AI, or is the line that is to blame. Don't you by any chance know what could have added that line ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have experienced the same problem but only at a specific time each day, starting three days ago.
It seems to be a global Azure issue, for more info take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44820387/app-throws-exception-that-web-config-was-modified-but-its-not)

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please post texts which only contain a reference to another topic as comments instead of answers.

Comment: Thank you! As I am a newbie at this forum I wasn't allowed to comment due to my reputation status. The problem discussed has been a nightmare for us lately and have made us work around the clock. So I was very anxious to  share what I know in the matter. I will absolutely follow your advice in the future.

Comment: did the workaround mentioned in the linked thread help? The issue stopped for me when I've applied chmod 444 on web.config (via azure console) and lowered app to 1 scale instance (this might have been a coincidence too, just sharing what did temporarily help in my case) Is the issie fixed on MS side yet?

Comment: For us, the problems stopped spontaneously on June 30. We were awaiting the next stop in order to analyze the state of the webapp better. The next step would have been trying the recommended setting WEBSITES_DYNAMIC_CACHE_FCN_MODE = 1.
Anyway, to use 1 scale instance for the app is an interesting idea since it seems to be some kind of race-condition for ownership of web.config triggering this problem.

Comment: so here I am again....after we've made a new publish, the issue appeared again, haven't  you experienced the issue again ? And/Or have you made any publish since the date? I've tried applying recommended settings, will see if that helps

Comment: after applying the settings and restarting the app, the issue no longer appears again